# Python program into a standard assembly?

Tags: python, assembly

Is it possible to convert Python programs to a Microprocessor standard assembly language like [IEEE-694](http://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/694-1985.html)?  The assembly syntax is close to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874731/program-on-assembly)
or this other one: http://www.ethicalhacker.net/content/view/152/2/

Comment: I've tried a lot. I found softwares like LLVM but the result was not the expected.

Comment: Take a look at the [Python on a chip](http://code.google.com/p/python-on-a-chip/) project.

Comment: what's the problem you are actually trying to solve?

Comment: According to [this page](http://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/694-1985.html), the IEEE-694 standard has been withdrawn.

Answer (score 16):

[Compile python to C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2525518/102937), then use a C compiler of your choice to get it down to assembly.

Alternatively, use [PyPy](http://pypy.org/), specifying LLVM as the target, and use the [LLVM Static Compiler](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llc.html) to yield assembly language for your target architecture.

Comment: I don't know how to use LLVM to get a very standard and basic assembly like IEEE-694.

Comment: I understand the idea of "standard assembly," but isn't that essentially what LLVM bytecode is?

Answer (score 7):

Not in the same way as C, FORTRAN, COBOL, etc.  Languages that support lambda calculus or automatic memory management cannot be compiled directly to assembly.  An interpreter can, however, be provided in microcode or in a bootstrap program to bridge the gap and allow "compiled" Python, LISP, etc.  (Some operations, such as garbage collection, are still carried out within the embedded interpreter packaged into the compiled binary.)

Comment: Thanks for inf. Actually,I'm thinking in compiling python to C, then disassembling with GDB. But still trying to find something better.

Comment: Actually that is a common misconception, common lisp has been a compiled language forever, and it even provides the disassemble function.
Check http://wiki.c2.com/?LispSucksInAssembly , some Lisps like corman lisp directly loaded assembly into memory without any other representation.

Comment: @SerialDev I meant that a garbage collector is required for full support for functional programming with closures.  A simple fixed point combinator cannot work without one.  This is not a LISP thing, it's a theoretical outcome.  A subset of LISP that did not allow fixed point functions could be compiled without embedded GC, or embedded GC could be included in a compiled binary to close the gap.  And including compiled libraries into LISP runtime is perfectly reasonable, and supported in Python as well.

Answer (score 5):

Since Python is a dynamically typed language, this would only be possible if the assembly program would use the runtime environment / library of Python to dynamically get objects.

So it would only be possible with some overhead.

But there is RPython from the [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) project. It is a restricted subset of the Python language (it is not longer dynamically typed and lacks most modules from Python's standard library). RPython programs can be translated to machine code (AFAIK it generates C code as a intermediate code).

Python itself generates a intermediate code for it's virtual machine. If you want to have a look at this code, use the [dis](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html) module from the Python standard library. This generates a assembly-like representation of your Python function. Keep in mind that a "real" microprocessor would not be able to use this and that the result might change with the Python version you are using.

Comment: I want to get a very basic and low-level assembly (without macros). I won't run it on a real microprocessor.